# How to view RoR controller instance variables in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table Projects each with 0 or more Categories. On my view, I want to display 0 projects until a JQuery click event associated with each category--i.e. when the user clicks "Food," I want to display all projects with category Food; when the user clicks "Photos," I want to display BOTH food and photos-related projects.

So on the jQuery click event I define an ajax call:

```
params = 'category_name=' + cat;
$.ajax({
  url: "/projects_controller/filter_list",
  data: params
})
```

where "cat" is the names of the Categories selected (in the format "Food Photography Journal etc")

In my projects_controller I started a filter_list method:

```
def filter_list
    @categories = []
    words = params[:category_name].split(/\W+/)
    words.each { |word| @categories.push(Category.where("name = ?", word))  }
   @projects = ...
end
```

But now I'm stuck. 1) How do I get all the projects associated with any of the categories in @categories? and 2) How do I display the @projects variable on my view? Right now I just display all like this:

```
<% Project.all.each do |project| %>
              <tr style="display:none" class="project <% project.categories.all.each do |cat| %><%= cat.name %> <% end %>">
                <td><%= project.filename %></td>
                <td><a href='project/<%= project.id %>'><%= project.location %></a>
                <td><% project.categories.all.each do |cat| %><%= cat.name %>, <% end %></td>
            <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your instance variables $categories, @projects are already available in the view. So in the view you can use `@project` rather than accessing the Class `Project` itself.

```
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

But probably you did not design your models correctly. Establish the correct [relationships](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) in your model. If a project belongs to a category, you can associate them as follows:

```
#models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :projects
end

#models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

#controllers/categories_controller.rb
def index
  @categories = Category.all #or use your own query
end

#views/categories/index.erb
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  # here you can get all projects under this category using 
  # category.projects
<% end %>
```

Note: i'm used to HAML, so sorry if my ERB syntax is wrong

Comment: I tried that and got the error " undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" for that line.

Comment: please check my updated answer which have more info and conventional model  design example

Answer (score 0):

The according view(s) to a controller `class` have have access to the *class level instance variables* (i.e. `@my_variable`).

Simply let `@projects = Project.all.each` in your *controller* and substitute `Project.all` with `@projects` in your *view*.

Comment: I tried that and got the error " undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" for that line

Comment: Then `Project.all` is returning `nil` which you are trying to iterate over.  Did you forget an _s_ in `projects` or any typos of this nature?

Comment: I figured it out--I defined @projects in the wrong definition in my controller. Stupid. But thank you so much!

Comment: @user1436111 Be careful making your ajax calls too, it doesn't look you have any responses set up for json requests.  (i.e. in your controller define a `respond_to do |format| format.json { render json: @projects }` to respond to json requests)